# Should I apply to developer jobs now with Thanksgiving and Christmas on the horizon

Tags: interviewing, job-search, holidays

I want to apply to Junior ASP.NET Core Web Developer Jobs as soon as next week, the week of Nov. 15th. Is this advisable with only 1 week away to Thanksgiving and 1 month away after that to Christmas? Should I wait until January? Thanks.

Comment: If they posted it, they're hiring. Time of year doesn't matter. If the job is out there and you think you'd be a good fit, apply immediately.

Comment: Can you explain this question, what do those holidays have to do with your application?

Comment: OP is probably waiting for a time when recruiters would be less focussed on wanting to go on holiday. Less distraction means better focus on the incoming CV's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need a job now because your are unemployed, or you have been told that your last day is in x days/weeks then you should be looking. There is no reason to wait until January to start the process.

You can't control how long the hiring process will take. It can take weeks or months even if everybody agrees that you are the perfect match. It takes time to schedule interviews, conduct interviews, decide, and then after the candidate accepts conduct the final background checks.

For all you know the perfect job will close in just a few days, but the new hire won't start until January.

Many companies don't have a hiring season. They win new work throughout the year. They have people quit or retire throughout the year.

If you find nothing worth apply to today, just look again tomorrow.  If it turns out those interview you go in the next few weeks, don't lead to the jobs you want, don't worry there are others that are in the pipeline.

Once you decide that you need a job, there is little reason to wait to start looking.

Comment: Great advice! I'm definitely applying now instead of waiting. Thanks.

Comment: In the end, applying just before Christmas might mean you're the first one in the queue to get interviewed 3rd of January. It will definitely not hurt.

Answer (score 12):

Sure, why not?

You might find that there are fewer companies advertising at this time of year, but if someone's posted a job advertisement, it's because they want to hire someone.

Comment: Ok. Would these companies be subpar since they are looking to hire devs during the end-of-year holiday season?

Comment: @rajndev Why do you think they'd be subpar?

Comment: Maybe because they could be desperate for devs as they're hiring even at the end-of-year holiday season. And being desperate could imply that their reputation is subpar. I'm most likely wrong. In any case, I'm going to just apply to jobs now. Thanks.

Comment: @rajndev that would be something to assess on a company-by-company basis during the application/interview process. Personally I wouldn't expect the time of year to have much correlation with the quality of the company.

Comment: @rajndev Not every company shuts down over holidays. Some allow the employees to take leave when they want. In any case, if they are desperate, that's actually a good bargaining position for the applicant to be in.

Comment: You are overthinking that. We hire devs as money comes in :-) Sales signs a new deal, we have money for a new employee, we hire. The only problem is that the company closes about 10 days over Christmas, so your holiday would need arranging.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear exactly what sort of situation you're worried about. Traditionally people don't quit their jobs during the holiday seasons but I did and started in early December. That is if you're thinking people won't hire during those times or something.

My only thought is since it is the holiday, you'll want to make sure you have whatever time you need off. It's unclear if you have a job right now with vacation built up but if you don't have a job applying today is a better idea than waiting for some magical time.

Comment: I'd second that last point and ask for a few days of extra time off as a pseudo-signing bonus.  If the company's reasonable you should be able to get it.  A newbie's going to be of limited value without assistance; and the people doing that will mostly be out at the time.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should continue to apply. Generally, (US) operations slow down during the holiday season — fewer people in the office and less work capacity — at the same time, people may not be able to interview you during this time and any interviews may have to be scheduled post season.

In other words, if they have posted a valid job listing, they are currently interviewing and simply fitting you into the schedule may be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recruiter here :)

It is true that the holiday season is not the most productive in the recruitment world but that can be an advantage as Recruiters have generally more time. Hiring managers are also looking forward to filling the roles asap.

Apply! However, instead of following the company's standard application process, contact recruiters directly on LinkedIn! It will get you through the door faster ;) Best of luck!